# AmCharts5 change color of node after it's displayed

Tags: amcharts

I am building a graph that displays domain names as nodes in a ForceDirected tree with AmCharts5 JS. The domains are displayed, and an asynchronous function checks for their availability, and tries to change their colors based on availability. This is where I'm stuck.

I have created an adapter that changes the color of the node based on the node's "availability" property:

```
 series.circles.template.adapters.add("fill", function(fill, target) {

   if (target.dataItem.dataContext.availability == 'unavailable') {
     return am5.color(0xb30000);
   }
   else {
     return am5.color(0x50b300);
   }
 });
```

This works well for nodes first instantiated with the availability property.

BUT in my use case, I *update* the availability property with `series.getDataItemById('nameOfNode').dataContext.availability = 'XYZ'` after getting results from an asynchronous query. This changes the dataContext, but it does not re-trigger the adapter, and the color stays the same.

Is there a way to re-trigger the adapter? Or manually force the color change on a specific dataItem? I browsed through the docs left and right and can't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to set fill on the Sprite after you change your dataContext, something like:

```
var circle = series.getDataItemById('nameOfNode').get("circle");
circle.set("fill", circle.get("fill"));
```